# Send proactive message based on setInterval data for Bot v4

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

So I'm trying to migrate my bot to v4 whilst adding a livechat functionality to it.

My use case is this:

I have a secondary non-azure bot which contains all my knowledge base, triggers and responses. This secondary bot has an API for direct communication, one of it's methods handles direct messages to the bot, let's call it "Talk". Then there is another method that fetches data from a livechat, this one we'll call "Poll", you can "Poll" a livechat each second and if there is a response there, you'll get it, if not, the API responds blank, which is acceptable and I'm ready to handle it in my code.

Where I'm stuck: I can send and receive messages to the Bot using "Talk", I can even start Polling a livechat conversation and see what's there. But I need to get what's there and send it back to the user.

I've tried declaring the context as "global" but it seems like i'm doing something wrong, I receive: *TypeError: Cannot perform 'set' on a proxy that has been revoked*

**This is my Talk function**
It works as expected, meaning that it always sends information to the secondary bot when the user types something to the AzureBot v4.

It also triggers the *islivechat* to true when it receives a SpecialAction to start a livechat (handled by the secondary bot).

```js
async function Talk(context, next) {
  var Talk_parameters = {
    "type": "talk",
    "parameters": {
        "userUrl": "aHR0cHM6Ly9zdGF0aWw=",
        "alreadyCame": true,
        "os": "V2luZG93cyAxMC4w",
        "browser": "RmlyZWZveCA2OA==",
        "disableLanguageDetection": true,
        "contextType": "V2Vi",
        "mode": "U3luY2hyb24=",
        "botId": "a3f3b9fb-********-5f6ba69bb9da",
        "qualificationMode": true,
        "language": "cHQ=",
        "space": "Default",
        "solutionUsed": "QVNTSVNUQU5U",
        "clientId": "UEZIdDhrMXVVbGU5b0lw",
        "useServerCookieForContext": false,
        "saml2_info": "",
        "pureLivechat": false,
        "userInput": Buffer.from(VArequestData.parameters.userInput).toString('base64'),
        "templateFormats": "",
        "contextId": VArequestData.parameters.contextId,
        "timestamp": new Date().valueOf()
    }
}

console.log(Talk_parameters);

return new Promise(resolve => {
  request({
      url: "https://sma********.com/servlet/chatHttp",
      method: "GET",
      body: Talk_parameters,
      headers: {},
      json: true
  }, async function (error, response, body) {
      if(!error)
          resolve(body);
  })
}).then(response_values => {
  console.log(response_values);

  VAresponseData.text = Buffer.from(response_values.values.text,'base64')
  VAresponseData.context = response_values.values.contextId
  VArequestData.parameters.contextId = response_values.values.contextId

  if (response_values.values.specialAction == "U3RhcnRQb2xsaW5n"){
    islivechat = true;
  }


})

}
```

**the SetInterval part**

```
setInterval(async function(){ 

  if (islivechat == true){
    Poll()
    console.log("Polling data!")
    msg();

  }

}, 1000);
```

**the Poll function**
When islivechat == true this guy runs each second, fetching data from the conversation with the secondary bot. I can get the exact value I need in the line "VAresponseData.livechatText = response_values.values.text", but I can't send it back to the user.

```js
async function Poll(context) {


    // Setting URL and headers for request
    var Polling_parameters = {

      type:"poll",
      parameters:{  
         lastPoll: VArequestData.parameters.lastPoll,
         mode : "Polling",
         contextId: VArequestData.parameters.contextId,
         botId : VArequestData.parameters.botId,
         qualificationMode : VArequestData.parameters.qualificationMode,
         language : VArequestData.parameters.language,
         space :  VArequestData.parameters.space,
         solutionUsed :"LIVECHAT",
         timestamp : new Date().valueOf()
      }
    }


console.log(Polling_parameters);

return new Promise(resolve => {
  request({
      url: "https://sma**************.com/servlet/chatHttp",
      method: "POST",
      body: Polling_parameters,
      headers: {},
      json: true
  }, async function (error, response, body) {
      if(!error)
          resolve(body);
  })



}).then(async (response_values) => {

  if(response_values.values.specialAction == "RW5kUG9sbGluZw=="){
    islivechat = false;

  }

  console.log(response_values);
  console.log("CONTEXT")
  console.log(response_values.values.contextId);
  console.log(Polling_parameters.parameters.contextId);
  VArequestData.parameters.lastPoll = response_values.values.serverTime
  VAresponseData.livechatText = response_values.values.text
  console.log('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx >>> ' + response_values.values.text)

  sendLivechatMsg();

})
}
```

**My failed attempt**: 
This function is declared outside of the main code, meaning it is accessible to any other function, but I receive *TypeError: Cannot perform 'set' on a proxy that has been revoked* when I run it. I tried running a console.log for it and the code doesn't even reach that part.

```js
async function sendLivechatMsg(globalContext){
  context = globalContext;
  await msg(VAresponseData.livechatText, context)
  .then(async function(){
    context.sendActivity(VAresponseData.livechatText)
    .then(

        console.log('activity')

    )
  })
  await next();
}
```

**The main stage**
I used the sample code for Bot v4 and changed just a few things

```js
class EchoBot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();

        // See https://aka.ms/about-bot-activity-message to learn more about the message and other activity types.
        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
               VArequestData.parameters.userInput = context.activity.text;

               await Talk(context, next)
                  .then(async function(data){

                    context.sendActivity(`'${ VAresponseData.text }'`) 
                    // context.sendActivity(`'${ VAresponseData.context }'`) 

                  }, error => {
                    console.log('ERROR: ' + error)
                  })

            await next();
        }
        );

        // this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
        //   setTimeout(() => startPolling(context), 3000);

        //     const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;
        //     for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; ++cnt) {
        //         if (membersAdded[cnt].id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {                
        //             // await context.sendActivity('Hello and welcome!');
        //         }
        //     }
        //     // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
        //     await next();
        // });
        this.onTurn
    }
}
```

The expected scenario is:

If the user is in a livechat and the variable "VAresponseData.livechatText" has a value, it needs to be sent to the user immediately, without the need for him to "Ask".

But I can't figure out a way to sent this back to the user.

Comment: A cursory scan shows you are missing an "await" in front of `context.sendActivity(VAresponseData.livechatText)` and `context.sendActivity(`'${ VAresponseData.text }'`)`. Add those and try again.